# Does Google Ads support macros in final url (landing page)?

Tags: google-ads-api

I want to promote my webpage in Google Ads to android phone users , and I need the Google advertising id for each phone to be in my landing page paramter like this. https://example.com/page?gaid=abcdefg

On some other platform , macros are supported so I can set the landing page url as [https://example.com/page?gaid={gaid}](https://example.com/page?gaid=%7Bgaid%7D)  to promote , but on google ads , I cannot find any explains about macros .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the list of available ValueTrack parameters [here](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6305348#available_valuetrack_parameters). Passing the Google Advertising Identifier is not supported, however.